# React <img src="#"/> tag in not showing image in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

Hello there It seems Basic but i'm lost.

tag is showing the alternate name for the image in the browser but not the image.

here is the image and code for that portion.

[image]

logo is it on it's position but not showing image of logo.

**portfolio.js**

```
const educationInfo = {
    display: true,
    schools : [
        {
            schoolName : "University of Engineering and Technology, Peshawar",
            logo: require("./assets/images/uet.png"),
            subHeader : "Bachelor of Electrical and Electronics Engineering",
            duration : "Aug 2016 to Oct 2020",
            desc : "Completed Bachelors with good grades, participated in multiple small 
               projects and successfully completed FYP on Commercial scale",
            descBullets : ["FYP: Raspberry-Pi based Cheque and Cash Deposit machine with 
               digital Wallet"]
         },
       ]
    };
```

**EducationCard.js**

```
import React,{createRef, useContext} from 'react'
import './EducationCard.css';
import StyleContext from '../../contexts/StyleContext';
import { Slide, Rotate } from 'react-reveal';
import { educationInfo } from '../../portfolio';

export default function EducationCard({school}){
     const {isDark } = useContext(StyleContext);
     const imgRef = createRef();
        
       #//..............

      <div className="education-card-left">
          <img
             crossOrigin={"anonymous"}
             ref={imgRef}
             className="education-roundedimg"
             src={educationInfo.schools.logo}
             alt={educationInfo.schools.schoolName}
             />
      </div>
```

Comment: please try to use path directly without using require and also use full path

if your file inside the public->img than path is like "img/<image_name>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require` inside of an object is unheard of. Here are a few things you can try:

1. Require/ Import your image on the top. Use it inside the object.

portfolio.js

```js
import Logo from "./assets/images/uet.png";

const educationInfo = {
    display: true,
    schools : [
        {
            schoolName : "University of Engineering and Technology, Peshawar",
            logo: Logo,
            subHeader : "Bachelor of Electrical and Electronics Engineering",
            duration : "Aug 2016 to Oct 2020",
            desc : "Completed Bachelors with good grades, participated in multiple small 
               projects and successfully completed FYP on Commercial scale",
            descBullets : ["FYP: Raspberry-Pi based Cheque and Cash Deposit machine with 
               digital Wallet"]
         },
       ]
    };
```

Or else, what you can do is use `eval`, like:

```js
const educationInfo = {
    display: true,
    schools : [
        {
            schoolName : "University of Engineering and Technology, Peshawar",
            logo: eval('require("./assets/images/uet.png")'),
            subHeader : "Bachelor of Electrical and Electronics Engineering",
            duration : "Aug 2016 to Oct 2020",
            desc : "Completed Bachelors with good grades, participated in multiple small 
               projects and successfully completed FYP on Commercial scale",
            descBullets : ["FYP: Raspberry-Pi based Cheque and Cash Deposit machine with 
               digital Wallet"]
         },
       ]
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line for importing image

```
import Logo from <image path>
```

And use it for image src

```
 <div className="education-card-left">
      <img
         crossOrigin={"anonymous"}
         ref={imgRef}
         className="education-roundedimg"
         src={Logo}
         alt={educationInfo.schools.schoolName}
         />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

import image by:

```js
import Logo from "./assets/images/uet.png"
```

and use `Logo` in source of image tag.